# Not getting exact output using User defined data types in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In CASSANDRA, I created a User defined data type,

```
 cqlsh:test> create type fullname ( firstname text, lastname text );
```

And i created a table with that data type and inserted into the table like this,

```
cqlsh:test> create table people ( id UUID primary key, names set < frozen <fullname>> );

cqlsh:test> insert into people (id, names) values (
      ...   now(), 
      ...   {{firstname: 'Jim', lastname: 'Jones'}}
      ... );
```

When i querying into the table iam getting output with some additional values like this

```
 cqlsh:test> SELECT * from people ;

 id                                   | names
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 3a59e2e0-14df-11e5-8999-abcdb7df22fc | {\x00\x00\x00\x03Jim\x00\x00\x00\x05Jones}
```

How can i get output like this???

```
 select * from people;

 id                                   | names
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
 69ba9d60-a06b-11e4-9923-0fa29ba414fb | {{firstname: 'Jim', lastname: 'Jones'}}
```

Comment: Your example is working fine for me. Can you provide details on the used Cassandra version/cqlsh? (printed when you start cqlsh)

Comment: It is working fine for me too. My version is cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2